# Font family phv does not work with font series mc

Tags: fonts

I am trying to get a narrow Arial font, and this used to work for me:

```
\fontfamily{phv}
\fontseries{mc}
\selectfont
```

When I try to compile the same .tex file again, I get warning and a different output. Here is the warning message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/phv/c/n' undefined
(Font) using 'T1/phv/m/n' instead on input line 17.
```

Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Minimum working example}
\author{Marko}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

{%
    \fontsize{16pt}{16pt}%
    \fontfamily{phv}%
    \fontseries{mc}%
    \selectfont%
    \begin{center}
        THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT\\%
        \textbf{THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT}%
    \end{center}
}

This is the rest of it...

\end{document}
```

And here is how the output looks for me:

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the latest latex release you may need to add additional declarations for the extended font handling (see ltnews31)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Minimum working example}
\author{Marko}

\makeatletter
\input{t1phv.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{phv}{c}{n}{
   <-> \Hv@@scale phvr8tn
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

{%
    \fontsize{16pt}{16pt}%
    \fontfamily{phv}%
    \fontseries{mc}%
    \selectfont%
    \begin{center}
        THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT\\%
        \textbf{THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT}%
    \end{center}
}

This is the rest of it...

\end{document}
```

But the standard fd file should probably be updated to include this declaration.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: Setting up "mc" inside the .fd file for phv was always wrong but in the past it didn't matter. With the new LaTeX it does matter, so yes, the standard .df files hsould get corrected if they contain such shape declarations.